# Knit function and dynamic file

Tags: r, knitr

I have some problems with function knit. I would like to create a report in different file everyday. So I would like to have a different name of this file each day.

And here is my problem:

When I want to do something like this:

`knit("Documents/20170726_xyz.Rnw",
"Documents/20170726_xyz.tex",encoding = 'UTF-8')`

Everything is ok in this case.
But when I do something like this:

```
if (wday(Sys.Date())==2){
  date2<-Sys.Date()-3
} else {
  date2<-Sys.Date()-1
}

knit(paste("Documents/",date2,"_xyz.Rnw", sep = ''",
      paste("Documents/",date2,"_xyz.tex", sep = ''",encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

I receive an error:

```
Error in readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { :
  cannot open file 'Dokumenty_2017-08-23_xyz.Rnw': No such file or directory
```

How could I do the second example properly?

Comment: You put some `"` instead of closing brackets : `)`. Replace your line which contains `knit` by : `knit(paste("Documents/",date2,"_xyz.Rnw", sep = ''),
      paste("Documents/",date2,"_xyz.tex", sep = ''),encoding = 'UTF-8')`

Comment: The same thing, but thank you.

Comment: Exactly the same error message ?

Comment: Yes. 
I tried to do sth like that:
x <- paste("Documents/",date2,"_xyz.Rnw", sep = '')
knit(x, encoding = 'UTF-8')

But there is the same error.

Comment: That's pretty wierd. Does it always say that the file named `Dokumenty_2017-08-23_xyz.Rnw` doesn't exisits ? Because obviousely, I don't see how your `paste`command generate a such string. Do you run your codes from the terminal ?
The string generated should be `Documents/2017-08-23_xyz.Rnw`. Have you ever a document named as this latter ?

Comment: The string is generated well. I know that it is weird because only the knit function works badly with this paste function

Comment: Does `knit('Documents/2017-08-23_xyz.Rnw','Documents/2017-08-23_xyz.tex',encoding='UTF-8')` works ?

Comment: No, it doesn't ;(

Comment: That means you don't have any file named `2017-08-23_xyz.Rnw` in the `Documents` directory.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand well this knit function. I would like to create by knit a report in folder Documents with name '20170823_xyz.Rnw'.

How can I do it, if my date in filename is a variable

Comment: The `Rnw` file has to be a compilator which exists and will be translate in a `pdf`or `tex`format for example. To write a `Rnw` open `Rstudio`and do `File`->`New file`->`R Sweave`. And then write your report following that example : https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/doc/Sweave.pdf